# why are single dimensional array types not listed in the constant pool table of a .class file?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, jvm, bytecode

If the code calls new int[0][0], the entry [[I will be placed in the constant pool table. A similar entry would be placed for a higher dimensional array.

However, if the code calls new int[0], no entry will appear in the constant pool table, just like nothing will appear for type int.

Also interesting is the fact that if the codeit calls new String[0][0] then "[[java/lang/String;" is added to the constant pool table, but if the code calls either new String() or new String[0], only "java/lang/String" is added to the constant pool table (no [ or ; in the second case).

Assuming that both my code and commons' BCEL API are parsing the pool table correctly, why are one-dimensional array types not listed in the constant pool table?

Comment: Have you tried with a non zero length?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several instructions that can be used to create arrays: `newarray`, `anewarray`, and `multinewarray`.

newarray creates a single dimensional primative array and doesn't require any constant pool entries.

anewarray takes a type and creates an array with elements of that type, initialized to null.

multinewarray takes the type of the array to be created and automatically fills in the elements with subarrays. This lets you create multidimensional arrays with a single instruction.

Of these, only the last requires a cp entry with the type of the array to be created. With the standard compiler, `new int[x]` uses the first, `new String[x]` uses the second, and `new int[x][y]` or `new String[x][y]` use the third.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to see your testcase.

My (limited) research indicates that the presence (or not) of the array class name strings in the constant pool depends on whether a *variable* is declared.

For example:

```
public class Test {
    static int[] a = new int[0];  // constant pool entry for "[I"
}

public class Test2 {
    static Object a = new int[0];  // no constant pool entry for "[I"
}
```

As @Antimony's answer points out, the bytecode instructions for creating arrays require either a base type constant pool entry or no constant pool entry at all.